# How to increase Bootstrap Modal Width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i've tried this but gone wrong

here's the css

```
body .modal-ku {
width: 750px;
}
```

and here's the failed result

[image]

Comment: in bootstrap you can use modal-sm, modal-lg for small and large size.

Comment: Can you share your specific html and css code. Some styles may be getting overriden

Comment: Can you share your full code Or you can see this example, in this model width can be changable. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h

Comment: @Hardevgun Please explain where in that example one can change the modal size? That is nothing but a simple, demo, fixed size modal.

Answer (score 353, accepted):

In your code, for the `modal-dialog` div, add another class, `modal-lg`:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

Or if you wanna centre your modal dialog, use:

```
.modal-ku {
  width: 750px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: @webNoob13 Great, thanks. But your issue might be totally different. This answer was written 5 years ago. Might not even be valid for your case. Kindly consider them.

Comment: `modal-lg` fixed it for me. You can also use `modal-xl` for even wider modals

Comment: @takanuva15 Thanks for your comment. But does it work with Bootstrap 3? I guess it was added in the later versions of bootstrap - 4 I guess.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman true it might not work with Bootstrap 3, but this was the 1st result I landed on while searching for this issue so others may find it useful (esp since more people will be using newer bootstraps)

Comment: This answer helped someone even after 7.5years. Thanks @PraveenKumarPurushothaman

Comment: **Yes** it works with Bootstrap 3.3.7 just fine.

Answer (score 57):

The easiest way can be inline style on `modal-dialog` div :

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
   <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1250px;">
      <div class="modal-content">
            ...

        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: what about all the fuss about being responsive n all?

Comment: @Abhinav Singh: You are right. Hard-code px value is not recommended. Percentage or Calc is recommended.

Comment: responsive: width:100%;max-width:1250px

Answer (score 46):

You can choose between `modal-lg` and `modal-xl` classes or if you want custom width then, set max-width property with inline css. For example,

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
```

or

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 80%;" role="document">
```

Comment: 'max-width' is the secret. Be ware of %. This will cause the dialog to accordion according to the width of your web page.

Answer (score 20):

In my case,

1. Giving a static width to the modal hurts the responsiveness.
2. The `modal-lg` class was not wide enough.

so the solution was

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
   .modal-xlg {
      width: 90%; 
   }
}
```

and use the above class instead of `modal-lg` class

Comment: Which previous class please ?

Comment: @JohnMax he means "use the above class"

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for 4.5.1 and there's already a build-in `modal-xl` class.

Comment: @JohnMax In accepted answer. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34014955/1791406

Comment: @Zeeshanef NO why you are referring to another answer, I did not mean that I meant the class on my answer, no the class on another answer

Answer (score 13):

I have also faced the same issue when increasing the width of the modal, the modal is not displaying in the centre. After playing around, I found the below solution.

```
.modal-dialog {
    max-width: 850px;
    margin: 2rem auto;
}
```

Upvote if this works for you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 10):

In Bootstrap 3 you need to change the modal-dialog. So, in this case, you can add the class modal-admin in the place where modal-dialog stands.

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    width: 600;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  .modal-content {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  }
  .modal-sm {
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In Bootstrap, the default width of `modal-dialog` is `600px`. But you can explicitly change its width. For instance, if you would like to maximize its width to the value of your choice, `800px` for instance, you do as following:

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

**Note**: This change sets to all modal dialog you use in your application. Also, my suggestion is it is best to have your own CSS rules defined and not to touch the core of the framework.

If you only want it to be set for specific modal dialog, use your own catchy class name as `modal-800` whose width is set to `800px`, as following:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-800">
      <div class="modal-content">

      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.modal-dialog.modal-800 {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Likewise, you can have class name as based on the width size like `modal-700` whose width is `700px`.

Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 6):

I had a large grid that needed to be displayed in the modal and just applying the width on body was not working correctly as table was overflowing though it had bootstrap classes on it. I ended up applying same width on `modal-body` and `modal-content` :

```
<!--begin::Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" style="width:980px;">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="">Title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true" class="la la-remove"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right">
                <div class="modal-body" style="width:980px;">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-brand m-btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!--end::Modal-->
```

Answer (score 6):

**2021 Sep.**
supported sizes by **Bootstrap 5**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">...</div>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">...</div>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">...</div>
```

Comment: ```modal-xl``` doesn't seem to work

Comment: in bootstrap 4 there is no `modal-xl` . Doublecheck if it is  Bootstrap4 or 5

Answer (score 5):

If you want to keep the modal responsive use % of width instead of pixels. You can do it in-line (see below) or with CSS.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="phpModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="width:80%;">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">HERE YOU TITLE</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body helpModal phpModal">
                        HERE YOUR CONTENT
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If you use CSS, you can even do different % for modal-sm and modal-lg.

Answer (score 3):

go to the `modal-dialog` div and add

```
 style="width:70%"
```

depending on the size you want

Comment: width: 70% does not work, but if you set min-width: 70% it does work. Test before answering

Answer (score 3):

First of all. The class to be sister is: modal-dialog

the native Bootstrap options can be:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
```

or

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
```

or

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are applying CSS on modal div.

you have to apply CSS on .modal-dialog

For example, see the following code.

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
 <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:xxxpx;"> <!-- Set width of div which you want -->
      <div class="modal-content">
           Lorem Ipsum some text...content 

        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Bootstrap also provides classes for setting div width.

For small modal use `modal-sm`

And for large modal `modal-lg`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do it is:

```
$(".modal-dialog").css("width", "80%");
```

where we can specify the width of the modal in terms of percentage of the screen.

Here is a working example to demonstrate the same:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".modal-dialog").css("width", "90%");
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For me what worked with bootstrap 5.2.1 is:

```
<div class="modal-dialog MyDialogWideningClass">
```

and

```
.MyDialogWideningClass
{
    --bs-modal-width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but to anyone looking, you now need to set the max-width property.

```
.modal-1000 {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 30px auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

default dialog size is 500px. If you want your dialog look large than default size than you should add class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered"  you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this happens due to the max-width of a modal being set to 500px and max-width of modal-lg is 800px I suppose setting it to auto will make your modal responsive

Answer (score 0):

n your code, for the modal-dialog div, add another class, modal-lg:

use modal-xl

Comment: don't  copy others answer

Answer (score 0):

You can define modal-xl but it is limited to 1140px maximum width so you can also define in line style max-width to the modal-dialog div like this if you need to define more width than that:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document" style="max-width:1400px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward solution if you're in a hurry and your boss is throwing more tasks at you:

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" style="width 100% !important; max-width: 650px !important;">
```

Answer (score -2):

```
.your_modal {
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: -400px; 
 }
```

margin left's value is half of modal's width.
I'm using this with Maruti Admin theme since it doesn't has class `.modal-lg .modal-sm`

Answer (score -2):

to easy,   if you want const so

````
```<div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width:1000px; max-height:1000px;">```
````