# How to fix tab modal width issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/mdPoKZe

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-with-tab">Modal with tabs</button>

<!-- Modal with tab -->
<div id="modal-with-tab" class="modal modal-with-tab fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 150%;">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Minimise this window to see the defect. After minimise, the width is not 100%
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal with tab -->
  
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Above code works fine. However, when the window is minimized, the width changes (not 100% anymore).
How do i fix the problem? Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Remove the inline style `style="width: 150%;"` (The modal overflow the screen). 
Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34014891/how-to-increase-bootstrap-modal-width. If these details not helpful please add a screenshot of the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `style="width: 150%;"`

Comment: This is not an answer, what you put is comment, please try to add a little description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try `max-width: 150%;` instead of `width: 150%;` that is

```
<div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 150%;">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Minimise this window to see the defect. After minimise, the width is not 100%
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Working demo**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-with-tab">Modal with tabs</button>

<!-- Modal with tab -->
<div id="modal-with-tab" class="modal modal-with-tab fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-width: 150%;">

    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        Minimise this window to see the defect. After minimise, the width is not 100%
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Modal with tab -->
  
  
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit this answer ok?

the solution is to add a class with the following code and remove the inline-style

```
.myModal {
   margin-left: 0
 }
```

I just tried it and it works

the problem is that bootstrap adds a margin for those sizes, just set it to 0